# How to get the keys of a table as string?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this table containing rgb colors and their values, i would like to loop trough it and get only the color names in **sequence** so i can tell my user the available colors:

```
local HUDColors = {
["Black"]   =   {0,0,0},
["White"]   =   {255,255,255},
["Red"]     =   {255,0,0},
}
```

Let me also add another question here, what's the difference between HUDColors.Black and HUDColors["Black"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the function `pairs`:

```
for key, value in pairs(HUDColors) do
    print( key )  -- will print all keys
end
```

---

There is no difference between `HUDColors.Black` and `HUDColors["Black"]`

Comment: forgot to add that i need them in sequence, is that possible?

Comment: @Mojimi lua-tables are like hash mappings. There are no sequences.

Comment: @Mojimi A table can have a sequence, as described in the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6)—just your top-level table as it is structured now doesn't have one; Your inner tables do.